# Smaato for Swift iOS: linker command with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, smaato

Xcode gets error which you can see below

[image: Error]

Smaato framework is Objective-C written framework but I use only Swift in my project. How can I manage this problem (I have only dragged and dropped Smaato framework to Xcode project space and checked that it works with import line)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check whether you have added following frameworks:
UIKit,Foundation,StoreKit,CoreTelephony,SystemConfiguration,MessageUI,AdSupport,QuartzCore,CoreLocation,CoreImage,CoreFoundation,EventKit

Answer (score 0):

Swift project does not directly recognize Objective C files added to the project.
There are a couple of steps after you drag and drop the framework to the project.

First, you have to create a Bridging-Header. 
Create a new Header file. Usually its named "project_name-Bridging-Header.h".

In Build Settings, search for "Objective-C Bridging Header" and set the value to Bridging header file name. You will have to provide the path from your project directory.

Now add `import <iSoma/iSoma.h>` in the Bridging Header. You should be then able to access the Objective file in Swift file.

Comment: My swift file has 'import iSoma' and I have created header.h file with contents - 

#ifndef header_h
#define header_h

#import <iSoma/iSoma.h>

#endif

But I'm still having this error

Comment: Integrating Swift
From version 8.x onward, the Smaato iOS SDK comes with a built-in Swift module structure. Just drag and drop the framework to the Swift project and you're set - no bridging headers required.

Comment: @MrGeorgeous Ok, I am not sure about Xcode 8, but I tried my above mentioned method and it works.